# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre etiquetas [vue.js] y [vuejs]? ¿No deberían ser sinónimas?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Estoy entrando en el mundo de [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org) y me puse a mirar etiquetas. Por lo pronto, veo que tenemos:

- [vue.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) con más de 800 preguntas y [vue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue) como sinónimo y [cierta orientación de uso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/info).
- [vuejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) con menos de 100 preguntas y ningún sinónimo, ni tampoco orientación de uso.
- Además, una veintena [tienen ambas etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs+vue.js).

¿No deberían estar juntas? En Stack Overflow [sí lo están](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/synonyms).

Por otra parte, en Stack Overflow [existe otra diferente [vuejs2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) que no sé si deberíamos incorporar.

Comment: sinonimos para todas.. y probablemente hicieron vuejs2 porque en vue 3 va  a cambiar bastante la forma de trabajar.. pero todo lo anterior sigue siendo valido.. yo esperaria para eso...

Comment: ¡gracias @gbianchi !